# Presenting Data in a bar chart AngularJS, How to make a good multi-bar chart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Suppose I have the bellow JSON:

```
[
        {
            month: "Jan",
            cost: 80,
            energy: 90
        },
        {
            month: "Feb",
            cost: 50,
            energy: 80
        },
        {
            month: "Mar",
            cost: 90,
            energy: 40
        },
        {
            month: "Apr",
            cost: 80,
            energy: 90
        },
        {
            month: "May",
            cost: 50,
            energy: 80
        },
        {
            month: "Jun",
            cost: 70,
            energy: 40
        },
        {
            month: "Jul",
            cost: 40,
            energy: 70
        },
        {
            month: "Aug",
            cost: 80,
            energy: 90
        },
        {
            month: "Sep",
            cost: 90,
            energy: 90
        },
        {
            month: "Oct",
            cost: 40,
            energy: 90
        },
        {
            month: "Nov",
            cost: 20,
            energy: 50
        },
        {
            month: "Dec",
            cost: 10,
            energy: 20
        },
    ];
```

How can i show this as a simple bar chart on my website?

- Y axis as a scale of numbers for cost/energy
- X axis displaying the month

I have had an attempt at this following a guide to purely use CSS and Javascript however the solution is incredibly basic and will only show me one bar of data at a time (i.e. cost OR Energy in a month.).

Here is an exmple of what I have tried:
HTML

```
<ul class="chart" style="width:{{width}}px; height:{{height}}px;" >
      <div class="y" style="width:{{height}}px;">{{yAxis}}</div>
      <div class="x">{{xAxis}}</div>
      <li ng-repeat="bar in data" class="bar" style="height:{{bar.cost / max * height}}px; width:{{width / data.length - 5}}px; left:{{$index / data.length * width}}px;"><span>{{bar.month}}:{{bar.cost}}</span></li>
    </ul>
```

Controller:

```
    $scope.width = 600;
    $scope.height = 400;
    $scope.yAxis = "Amount";
    $scope.xAxis = "Month";
    $scope.data = dataService.usage;
    $scope.max = dataService.max;
// Dataservice is a factory which returns the aformentioned JSON
```

CSS:

```
.chart {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin: 60px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.y {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.x {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.bar {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;


 bottom: 0;
}
```

This approach looks awful on the page and the Y Axis doesn't show up correctly either.

Is there a better method to display my data in Angular?

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use a [charting library](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) for this.